# in_array() on multidimensional array

Tags: php

I want to find an array inside an array by its value.

Example:
It returns "Match not found", while "Peter" is inside the $people array.
But I can found "Joe".

```
$people = array(
  "Peter" => array (
        "test" => 0
    ),
  "Joe"
);

if (in_array("Peter", $people))
  {
     echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
     echo "Match not found";
  }
```

How can I found "Peter" in the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) search for values, but in your code `Peter` is a key. Then you can use [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) instead:

```
$people = array(
    "Peter" => array (
        "test" => 0
    ),
    "Joe"
);

if (array_key_exists("Peter", $people))
{
    echo "Match found";
}
else
{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

Output

```
Match found
```

you can combine both since the name you're searching is sometimes the value like `"Joe"` in your example.

```
if (array_key_exists("Peter", $people) || in_array("Peter", $people)) {
    echo "Match found";
} else {
    echo "Match not found";
}
```